# Can you sync/bind one OscillatorNode's frequency with another?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

So, I am creating two [oscillators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode) using the Web Audio API:

```js
let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

let o1 = audioCtx.createOscillator();
o1.type = "sawtooth";
o1.frequency.value = 220;
o1.connect(audioCtx.destination);
o1.start();

let o2 = audioCtx.createOscillator();
o2.type = "square";
o2.frequency.value = o1.frequency.value;
o2.connect(audioCtx.destination);
o2.start();

o1.frequency.setValueAtTime(392, audioCtx.currentTime + 3);
```

As you can see, I use the first oscillator's frequency to set the frequency of the second oscillator. This is because I would like to effectively combine the sound of these oscillators together. I change the frequency of the first oscillator 3 seconds later, but as you can hear, the frequency of the second is not updated as well.

So does the Web Audio API provide an event that I can subscribe to (e.g. `onfrequencychange`) or something else that will allow me to auto-update the frequency of the second oscillator whenever the first one is changed? Maybe some way of binding/connecting to
 [OscillatorNode.frequency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode/frequency) (which is an [AudioParam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam))?

Sure, I could do this:

```
o1.frequency.setValueAtTime(392, audioCtx.currentTime + 3);
o2.frequency.setValueAtTime(392, audioCtx.currentTime + 3);
```

...but for the sake of this question, let's assume that at the point when I'm updating the first oscillator's frequency, my application has lost a reference to the second oscillator.

Essentially, I'm trying to make the two oscillators behave as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear why you want two oscillators with exactly the same frequency, but one way to achieve that:

```
let s = new ConstantSourceNode(audioCtx, {offset: 220});
s.connect(o1.frequency);
s.connect(o2.frequency);
s.start();
...
s.offset.setValueAtTime(392, audioCtx.currentTime + 3);
```

Thus `s` controls the frequency of both oscillators.

And there's no `onfrequencychange` event.  How would that work when you can automate the frequency such that it changes every sample frame, like what happens if you use a `linearRampToValueAtTime` or other automation?

Comment: Thanks! After playing with this, I found that the initial frequency of each oscillator should also be set to zero, since the `ConstantSourceNode` *adds* to the frequency, it doesn't simply *replace* it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I always forget the `.value` is added to whatever is connected to the `AudioParam`.